# Real-time data Arduino to Android TCP

Tags: java, android, tcp, arduino, real-time

I am an electrical engineer working on my senior capstone project. The project is a portable ECG device which uses an [Arduino MKR1000](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMKR1000). I am developing an Android application which I want to graph real-time data received from the Arduino using a TCP connection. I am not very familiar with coding and especially new to networking using TCP. Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack, Thomas! Please provide us with some code and your attempts to solve this problem. This site is used for asking questions and getting answers, not free labor.

Comment: Hi @HudsonTaylor, I am not looking for code just some general advice as I am unsure where to start. I am not a programmer or computer science major so I am not familiar with any of this.  Thanks

Comment: Asking for general advice is still off-topic for being too broad.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of things you should know for doing this. first you should know the concept of android programming specially with android studio. next you should make a simple TCP/IP connection with your board.first you make your board as a server and then try to connect to it as client.my simple [AndroidClientSimpleMessenger](https://github.com/sinadarvi/AndroidClientSimpleMessenger) and [JavaServerSimpleMessenger](https://github.com/sinadarvi/JavaServerSimpleMessenger) should be useful for knowing base of this work.and at last you should draw a real-time graph. and GraphView library of appsthatmatter in github should be helpful. i used it and it is real-time.